# SQL Query to return patients who have not had certain appointment status in last 3 years

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join

I am working with some patient data, trying to return a list of all the patients who have not had a "Kept"(K) appointment in the last 3 years.
This is not a standard SQL database but a proprietary one that has been modified so not all SQL functions and syntaxes work but most do. It is closest to MySQL according to the technicians at the company we get the software from.
There is a PATIENT table. This contains general demographic info on the patient with the Primary Key being a unique ID called PATUNIQUE.
The other table being used is the APPT(appointments) table which includes several STATUS codes. I'm only looking at the 'K' status.

The query I have so far is
`

```
SELECT p.PATUNIQUE, a.BILLUNIQUE as "Acct#", a.STATUS, a.DATE
FROM PATIENT p
INNER JOIN APPT a
ON p.PATUNIQUE = a.PATUNIQUE
WHERE (a.DATE >= CURDATE()-1095 AND a.DATE < CURDATE())
AND (a.LOCATION = :LOCATION)
AND (a.PATUNIQUE NOT IN 
    (SELECT **ap.PATUNIQUE, COUNT(ap.STATUS)**
    FROM APPT ap 
    WHERE ap.STATUS in ('K')
    Group by ap.PATUNIQUE))
ORDER BY a.DATE
```

`I first tried the query below, but it would only result is appointments that were not status 'K'. So patients who have had a 'K' in the last 3 years were showing in the results.`

```
SELECT p.PATUNIQUE, a.BILLUNIQUE as "Acct#", a.STATUS, a.DATE
FROM PATIENT p
INNER JOIN APPT a
ON p.PATUNIQUE = a.PATUNIQUE
WHERE (a.DATE >= CURDATE()-1095 AND a.DATE < CURDATE())
AND (a.LOCATION = :LOCATION)
AND (a.STATUS NOT IN ('K'))
ORDER BY a.DATE
```

`
The idea I had was count all the 'K' statuses from each patient. If the patient has no 'k' then they will not appear in the inner query result. My issue is that our software does not allow for an inner select query to return two columns so I keep getting an error. Is there another way I can write this? I cannot write SQL functions or scripts, I can only query with SELECT

Answer (score 0):

> list of all the patients who have not had a "Kept"(K) appointment in the last 3 years

Why not use `NOT EXISTS`?

```
select p.*
from patient p
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from appt a
    where 
        a.patunique = p.patunique 
        and a.location = :location 
        and a.date >= current_date - interval 3 years -- or CURDATE()-1095...
        and a.status = 'K'
)
```

`NOT EXISTS` has been standard SQL for very long, and should be supported everywhere. The key feature is the *correlated* subquery: the SQL in the `not exists` clause has access to columns defined in the outer `from` clause (here, `p.patunique` is used for correlation). You would need to check if your database supports that feature.

---

We could also express the logic with an anti-`left join`, although that might be less efficient; the pattern consists in trying to join with a K appointment (`left join`), and then make sure that there was no match (`where` clause):

```
select p.*
from patient p
left join appt a 
    on  a.patunique = p.patunique 
    and a.location = :location 
    and a.date >= current_date - interval 3 years
    and a.status = 'K'
where a.patunique is null
```

Comment: While this didn't get me the results I needed, it has brought me much closer. Thank you